# How to avoid symfony using the public-folder for assetic:install

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

I have a bundle and I do not want that files inside the public-folder will be transfered to the web-folder with assetic:install. Instead I am using assetic:dump to only transfer defined files.
How can I avoid that my public bundle files will be transfered if I use assetic:install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't put these files into `...Bundle/Resources/public`, move them. You should be able to reference them from any other folder using `@`-notation in your `{% javascripts %}` or `{% stylesheets %}` anyway:

```
{% javascripts 
    '@YourBundle/Resources/private/js/some-private-script.js'
%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

And Assetic's `assets:install` command should ignore them, too, now.